# Replace @import url google font with local font

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-font-api

I want to replace the google font loading in my theme with local font loading:

```
/*@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Shadows+Into+Light&display=swap');*/

@import url('/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/fonts/shadows-into-light-regular.woff2');
```

But it is not replacing the correct font if i look at the frontend.

In the headline css i find font-family: 'Shadows Into Light', cursive;

With Google font it is loading the correct font style but not with my local file.

Please note that i have downloaded the same font from google under the link on top directly. So the font file should be 100% identical.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied the code i found under the google link and replaced the font url. And it was done.

For example:

```
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Shadows Into Light';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/shadowsintolight/v15/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD5.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

and replaced the url https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/shadowsintolight/v15/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD5.woff2
With
/wp-content/theme/theme1/fonts/shadowsintolight/v15/UqyNK9UOIntux_czAvDQx_ZcHqZXBNQzdcD5.woff2

done

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly embed webfonts like this - you're missing @font-face styles. Read more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face).

Additionally, I can recommend [Google Fonts Helper](https://gwfh.mranftl.com/fonts) as a way to download webfonts from Google. It automatically generates the correct stylesheet you need to use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i think copy paste the google font face is better because then it is identical like before without reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `@font-face` of CSS.
If you want to use the local font file, you will need to add the path of the file in the `src` attribute.

I am attaching my code snippet here. Hope it helps.

```css
@font-face {
font-family: shadows-into-light-regular;
src: url(/wp-content/themes/storefront-child/fonts/shadows-into-light-regular.woff2');
}
```